# Problem with regular expressions '-' between numbers and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Let's say I have this string

```
'1. A4  1... d5  2. c4  2... Yf6  3. NP3  3... dxc4  4. BO3  4... BK4  5. e3  5... Bf3  6. Q3  6... e6  7. Bc4  7... B4  8. O-O  8... B3  9. b3  9... O-O  10. B3  10... Re8  11. Q7  1-0'
```

I want to remove the numbers not attached to letters and if you scroll to the end I want the `1-0` removed as well, so something like this

```
['A4', 'd5', ..., 'O-O', ..., 'Q7']
```

So I tried this,

```
re.findall(r'(?:[^\W\d_]+\d|\d+[^\W\d_])[^\W_]*|[^\W\d_]+', text)
```

but got this,

```
['A4', 'd5', ..., 'O', 'O', ..., 'Q7']
```

So it is removing the `-` for `1-0` which I want, but also to `O-O`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is removing the `-` for `1-0`"? Isn't it removing *all* of `1-0`?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I copy the wrong stuff, MY BAD didn't view it

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with regular expressions here? You can just `split` the string and take the odd numbered indices:

```py
>>> s = '1. A4  1... d5  2. c4  2... Yf6  3. NP3  3... dxc4  4. BO3  4... BK4  5. e3  5... Bf3  6. Q3  6... e6  7. Bc4  7... B4  8. O-O  8... B3  9. b3  9... O-O  10. B3  10... Re8  11. Q7  1-0'
>>> list(itertools.islice(s.split(), 1, None, 2))
['A4',
 'd5',
 'c4',
 'Yf6',
 'NP3',
 'dxc4',
 'BO3',
 'BK4',
 'e3',
 'Bf3',
 'Q3',
 'e6',
 'Bc4',
 'B4',
 'O-O',
 'B3',
 'b3',
 'O-O',
 'B3',
 'Re8',
 'Q7']
```

Comment: the OP's requirement is `remove the numbers not attached to letters`, this answer works but would fail on 2 digits numbers, or numbers with unknown lengths.

Comment: @Jared I don't believe it would fail at all. There's nothing about this solution that distinguishes 1-digit from 2- or more digit numbers, or even cares about the contents of each token. The input is a list moves in a single game of chess. It seems pretty clear the poster wants to filter out the turn numbers from the moves.

Answer (score 1):

Find all words with at least a single letter in it :

```
re.findall(r'\S*[a-zA-Z]\S*', text)

['A4', 'd5', 'c4', 'Yf6', 'NP3', 'dxc4', 'BO3', 'BK4', 'e3', 'Bf3', 'Q3', 'e6', 'Bc4', 'B4', 'O-O', 'B3', 'b3', 'O-O', 'B3', 'Re8', 'Q7']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate through the string and `isidigt` to check if each item contains a digit or not.

```
str1 = '1. A4  1... d5  2. c4  2... Yf6  3. NP3  3... dxc4  4. BO3  4... BK4  5. e3  5... Bf3  6. Q3  6... e6  7. Bc4  7... B4  8. O-O  8... B3  9. b3  9... O-O  10. B3  10... Re8  11. Q7  1-0'
output = list(filter(None, [i if i.replace("-","").isdigit()==False else None for i in str1.replace(".", "").split(' ')]))
```

print(output) gives:

```
['A4', 'd5', 'c4', 'Yf6', 'NP3', 'dxc4', 'BO3', 'BK4', 'e3', 'Bf3', 'Q3', 'e6', 'Bc4', 'B4', 'O-O', 'B3', 'b3', 'O-O', 'B3', 'Re8', 'Q7']
```

Comment: but you have the '1-0' at the end and I don't want that, all that have 'number - number' are no good